# clean, breakable left-aligned array-like environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, page-breaking, align, arrays

The centered, yet left-aligned aspect of `\begin{array}{lll} ... \end{array}` is what I usually go with to give a list of conditions. My only problem with it, is that it is not breakable, so I try to replace it with `\begin{align}... \end{align}`-like environments.

The closest result I get is with `\begin{flalign*} ...\end{flalign*}`. Then I can use `\allowdisplaybreaks[2]`. But I generally have to play around with `&`'s to get the "look" I want.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve a breakable left-aligned array-like environment?

Below is a concrete example, comparing the result with both `array` and `flalign`.

(Also, as a side question, is it me, or are there some irregularities in the vertical spacing in the `flalign` version: namely there is more vertical spacing between line 5 and line 6, than between others, because of the subscript at the end of line 6. If so, can I avoid that?)

Thanks for reading!

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}
\sloppy

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\newcommand{\labarrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{#1}{\rightarrow} }}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{N}}}
\newcommand{\diam}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1 \rangle}}
\newcommand{\da}{\mathopen{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\model}{\mathbb{M}}
\newcommand{\logic}[1]{\textsf{#1}}


\allowdisplaybreaks[2]

\begin{document}



$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\model,w,g \models x & \textup{ iff } & g(x)=w\\
\model,w,g \models \logic{turn}_i & \textup{ iff } & \rho(x)=i\\
\model,w,g \models @_x \phi & \textup{ iff } & g(x)\in|\model| \textup{ and }         \model,g(x),g\models\phi\\
\model,w,g \models \da x.\phi & \textup{ iff } & \model,w,g[g(x):=w]\models\phi\\
\model,w,g \models [!\N_i]\phi & \textup{ iff } & {\model|_{\N_i(w)}},w,g \models \phi\\
\model,w,g \models \diam{\alpha}\phi & \textup{ iff } & \textup{there exists some }v\textup{ with }(w,v)\in||\alpha||^\model\\ & &\textup{and }\model,v,g \models \phi
\end{array}
$$




\begin{flalign*}
&&&\model,w,g \models x && \textup{ iff } && g(x)=w&&\\
&&&\model,w,g \models \logic{turn}_i && \textup{ iff } && \rho(x)=i&&\\
&&&\model,w,g \models @_x \phi && \textup{ iff } && g(x)\in|\model| \textup{ and } \model,g(x),g\models\phi&&\\
&&&\model,w,g \models \da x.\phi && \textup{ iff } && \model,w,g[g(x):=w]\models\phi&&\\
&&&\model,w,g \models [!\N_i]\phi && \textup{ iff } && {\model|_{\N_i(w)}},w,g \models \phi&&\\
&&&\model,w,g \models \diam{\alpha}\phi && \textup{ iff } && \textup{there exists some }v\textup{ with }(w,v)\in||\alpha||^\model&&\\ 
&&& && &&\textup{and }\model,v,g \models \phi&
\end{flalign*}





\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `alignat` rather than `flalign`. Note the `tabular` used for splitting the last item into two lines, so that no page break is taken here and the vertical spacing is better.

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show page frames
\setlength{\textheight}{5cm} % just to induce a page break
\usepackage{lipsum} % for some text

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\labarrow}[1]{\overset{#1}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathsf{N}}
\newcommand{\diam}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
\newcommand{\da}{\mathopen{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\model}{\mathbb{M}}
\newcommand{\logic}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

% for the ``iff'' separator
\newcommand{\eiff}{\hspace{1.5em}\textup{iff}\hspace{1.5em}} % adjust the amount

\allowdisplaybreaks[2]

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\model,w,g \models x                 && \eiff &&
  g(x)=w \\
&\model,w,g \models \logic{turn}_i    && \eiff &&
  \rho(x)=i \\
&\model,w,g \models @_x \phi          && \eiff &&
  g(x)\in|\model| \textup{ and } \model,g(x),g\models\phi \\
&\model,w,g \models \da x.\phi        && \eiff &&
  \model,w,g[g(x):=w]\models\phi \\
&\model,w,g \models [!\N_i]\phi       && \eiff &&
  {\model|_{\N_i(w)}},w,g \models \phi \\
&\model,w,g \models \diam{\alpha}\phi && \eiff &&
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  there exists some $v$ with $(w,v)\in||\alpha||^\model$ \\
  and $\model,v,g \models \phi$
  \end{tabular}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest `alignat`.  Consider

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
   &xx &\quad& yy &\quad& zz \\
   &pp && qq && rr
\end{alignat*}
```

Then each piece of mathematics will be left aligned in its column, and the space between the columns will be given by `\quad`.  You could adjust this spacing by using other spacing commands, `\hspace{1em}` will be the same as one quad.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\labarrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{#1}{\rightarrow} }}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{N}}}
\newcommand{\diam}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1 \rangle}}
\newcommand{\da}{\mathopen{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\model}{\mathbb{M}}
\newcommand{\logic}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

\allowdisplaybreaks[2]

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\model,w,g \models x &\quad& \textup{ iff } &\quad& g(x)=w\\
&\model,w,g \models \logic{turn}_i && \textup{ iff } && \rho(x)=i\\
&\model,w,g \models @_x \phi && \textup{ iff } && g(x)\in|\model| \textup{ and } \model,g(x),g\models\phi\\
&\model,w,g \models \da x.\phi && \textup{ iff } && \model,w,g[g(x):=w]\models\phi\\
&\model,w,g \models [!\N_i]\phi && \textup{ iff } && {\model|_{\N_i(w)}},w,g \models \phi\\
&\model,w,g \models \diam{\alpha}\phi && \textup{ iff } && \textup{there exists some }v\textup{ with }(w,v)\in||\alpha||^\model\\ 
& && &&\textup{and }\model,v,g \models \phi
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```